# how can I merge a numpy array with a loop

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I am trying to fulfill an array with the data from other two variables

my code is like:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = [200,50,125,275,350]
x2 = [475,575,700,700,575]

#array = np.array([[200,475],[50,575],[125,700],[275,700],[350,575]])
array = np.array(
                    for j in range(5):
                      #for i in range(2):
                        [x1[i],x2[i]]
                    )
```

thank you in advance

> Expected Result array([[200,475],
> [50,575],
> [125,700],
> [275,700],
> [350,575]])

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` then convert to list and use [`numpy.asarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) to get as array Or you can use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html).

```
import numpy as np

x1 = [200,50,125,275,350]
x2 = [475,575,700,700,575]

res = np.asarray(list(zip(x1,x2)))

res_2 = np.column_stack((x1,x2))
```

---

```
>>> res
array([[200, 475],
       [ 50, 575],
       [125, 700],
       [275, 700],
       [350, 575]])

>>> res_2
array([[200, 475],
       [ 50, 575],
       [125, 700],
       [275, 700],
       [350, 575]])
```

Comment: Thnak you very much

I share with you the whole code:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1a_l1fpG4Gy2e29ybrgzhOSqw9Se26l_X?usp=sharing

Comment: @DanielMolina, OK, I see this, What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by concatenation, but you can also do it just by building a 2D array and transposing:

```
import numpy as np
x1 = [200,50,125,275,350]
x2 = [475,575,700,700,575]

a = np.array([x1,x2]).T
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[200 475]
 [ 50 575]
 [125 700]
 [275 700]
 [350 575]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time,

I share with you the complete code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1a_l1fpG4Gy2e29ybrgzhOSqw9Se26l_X?usp=sharing

Comment: ZIp also works for this.  Whichever makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a built in function of numpy - numpy.stack()

```
import numpy as np

x1 = [200,50,125,275,350]
x2 = [475,575,700,700,575]

arr = np.stack((x1, x2), axis=1)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[200 475]
 [ 50 575]
 [125 700]
 [275 700]
 [350 575]]
```

Comment: Thnak you very much:

I share the whole code: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1a_l1fpG4Gy2e29ybrgzhOSqw9Se26l_X?usp=sharing